# Need to select table data into distinct columns based on a date in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not sure what I need here, looks sort of like I could use a pivot but I don't think it's that complicated and would like to avoid pivot if I can as I haven't used it much (er, at all).

I have data like this:

```
ID      score   notes               CreateDate
1661    9.2     8.0 on Sept 2010    7/22/2010
1661    7.6                         11/4/2010
1661    7.9                         6/10/2011
1661    8.3                         9/28/2011
1661    7.9                         1/20/2012
```

I want to organize all that data on to one row with the oldest date being first and then use the next oldest date, then next oldest...until I use 4 or 5 dates.  So the end result would look something like this:

```
ID      score1  notes1              date1       score2  notes2  date2       score3  notes3  date3       score4  notes4  date4
1661    9.2     8.0 on Sept 2010    7/22/2010   7.6     blah    11/4/2010   7.9     blah2   6/10/2011   8.3     blah3   9/28/2011
```

Answer (score 5):

PIVOT would be tricky in this situation, since you have more than one column per test (PIVOT works well if you only wanted to show Score1, Score2, Score3, etc). Fortunately, you can create a simple (if long-winded) solution with CASE statements:

```
select
  ID,

  max(case when RowNum = 1 then Score else null end) as Score1,
  max(case when RowNum = 1 then Notes else null end) as Notes1,
  max(case when RowNum = 1 then CreateDate else null end) as Date1,

  max(case when RowNum = 2 then Score else null end) as Score2,
  max(case when RowNum = 2 then Notes else null end) as Notes2,
  max(case when RowNum = 2 then CreateDate else null end) as Date2,

  max(case when RowNum = 3 then Score else null end) as Score3,
  max(case when RowNum = 3 then Notes else null end) as Notes3,
  max(case when RowNum = 3 then CreateDate else null end) as Date3,

  max(case when RowNum = 4 then Score else null end) as Score4,
  max(case when RowNum = 4 then Notes else null end) as Notes4,
  max(case when RowNum = 4 then CreateDate else null end) as Date4,

  max(case when RowNum = 5 then Score else null end) as Score5,
  max(case when RowNum = 5 then Notes else null end) as Notes5,
  max(case when RowNum = 5 then CreateDate else null end) as Date5

from

(
select 
   *, row_number() over (partition by ID order by CreateDate) as RowNum
from 
   mytable
) tt

group by
  ID
```

This is hard-coded to cover 5 tests.  It will be OK with less, but won't display a 6th.  You can obviously create more CASE statements to handle more tests.

Comment: Actually `PIVOT` wouldn't help here anyway as you can't pivot on multiple columns. The `CASE` version is the more flexible of the two. It can be shortened a bit as `else null` is redundant as that is the default behaviour anyway.

Comment: Can `PIVOT` create a **single row** result as OP seemingly wants?

Comment: @MartinSmith makes a good point about PIVOT not handling multiple columns.  Technically, it can be done by starting with UNPIVOT but yes, it gets messy.

Comment: @ExactaBox - It would get extremely messy as the datatypes are numeric, date, and string. Even if all the same datatype `UNPIVOT ... PIVOT` would be less efficient than just using `CASE` though.

Comment: I said I'd like to avoid pivot if I can but not opposed to using it.  Maybe I'm just tired for the day and didn't wan't to learn any more for the day.

I'll try the CASE solution and see where that gets me.  If you have a solution for pivot, I'll take a look as that might be more elegant looking code than the CASE.

Thank You.

Comment: @MartinSmith is correct that CASE is preferable in this situation.  This is definitely not a good example on which to learn PIVOT or to use it for the first time. I've amended my response (the code has not been altered).

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes PIVOT can be used if you implement UNPIVOT as well, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just because I love pivots, I will show you how this can be done using the PIVOT function.  In order to get the result with the PIVOT function you will first want to UNPIVOT your multiple columns `score`, `notes` and `createdate`.  The unpivot process will convert the multiple columns into multiple rows.

Since you are using SQL Server 2008 you can use CROSS APPLY to unpivot your data, the first part of the query will be similar to:

```
;with cte as
(
  select id, score, notes, createdate,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by createdate) seq
  from yourtable
) 
select id, col, value
from 
(
  select t.id, 
    col = col + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
    value
  from cte t
  cross apply
  (
    values
      ('score', cast(score as varchar(10))),
      ('notes', notes),
      ('date', convert(varchar(10), createdate, 120))
  ) c (col, value)
) d;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/093e8/2). Doing this gets your data in the format:

```
|   ID |    COL |            VALUE |
| 1661 | score1 |             9.20 |
| 1661 | notes1 | 8.0 on Sept 2010 |
| 1661 |  date1 |       2010-07-22 |
| 1661 | score2 |             7.60 |
| 1661 | notes2 |           (null) |
| 1661 |  date2 |       2010-11-04 |
| 1661 | score3 |             7.90 |
```

Now you can apply the PIVOT function:

```
;with cte as
(
  select id, score, notes, createdate,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by createdate) seq
  from yourtable
) 
select id, col, value
from 
(
  select t.id, 
    col = col + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
    value
  from cte t
  cross apply
  (
    values
      ('score', cast(score as varchar(10))),
      ('notes', notes),
      ('date', convert(varchar(10), createdate, 120))
  ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (score1, notes1, date1, score2, notes2, date2,
              score3, notes3, date3, score4, notes4, date4,
              score5, notes5, date5)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/093e8/1).

Then if you were going to have an unknown number of values for each `id`, you could implement dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col + cast(seq as varchar(10))) 
                    from 
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by id order by createdate) seq
                      from yourtable
                    ) d
                    cross apply 
                    (
                      select 'score', 1 union all
                      select 'notes', 2 union all
                      select 'date', 3
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by seq, col, so
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select t.id, 
                col = col + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
                value
              from
              (
                select id, score, notes, createdate,
                  row_number() over(partition by id order by createdate) seq
                from yourtable
              ) t
              cross apply
              (
                values
                  (''score'', cast(score as varchar(10))),
                  (''notes'', notes),
                  (''date'', convert(varchar(10), createdate, 120))
              ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/093e8/5). Both versions give the result:

```
|   ID | SCORE1 |           NOTES1 |      DATE1 | SCORE2 | NOTES2 |      DATE2 | SCORE3 | NOTES3 |      DATE3 | SCORE4 | NOTES4 |      DATE4 | SCORE5 | NOTES5 |      DATE5 |
| 1661 |   9.20 | 8.0 on Sept 2010 | 2010-07-22 |   7.60 | (null) | 2010-11-04 |   7.90 | (null) | 2011-06-10 |   8.30 | (null) | 2011-09-28 |   7.90 | (null) | 2012-01-20 |
```

Comment: @ExactaBox what can I say, [I love pivots](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pivot/topusers).